# In Clash of Clans what does XP do when donating troops to clan?

Tags: clash-of-clans

In Clash of Clans when requesting troops from clan, can one do it to often? I notice when you donate you get XP. Is there some way to see another players XP and then if it's negative or something no one would donate troops to you?

So what I'm really wondering is how do I know if I'm requesting too many troops compared to how many troops I donate, but from the answers it sounds like there's no connection?

Comment: I deleted my answer because it's now currently obsolete. https://gamesupport.supercell.net/hc/en-us/articles/203201283 has made no exp gains or any achievement rewards, and I have no idea how you can tell who sent you the rewards.

Answer (score 4):

EXP in Clash of Clans is pretty much like experience in any other game.
*It can be found on the top left-hand corner of the main screen and profile screen.*

The experience you gain then is placed alongside a level system, with EXP cut-offs, a number that increases as you increase your EXP, but the requirements to get to the next level also increases.

**It basically shows how much a player has invested into a game.** Or for most MMORPGs; their character.

You pretty much earn experience by:

- Upgrading Buildings
- Donating Troops
- Earning Achievements.
- Destroying townhalls in attacks
- Clearing plants/rocks from your village.

*For all we know, there could be a Level 30 player with a Townhall Level 8 in Challenger League amongst all the Level 90+ players.*

---

#### Answering your question:

> It basically shows how much a player have invested into a game.

The only thing EXP is useful for is for unlocking decorations.
The more EXP you have, thus giving you a higher level, the more decorations you unlock.

---

If you need more information, you can find them in the Wiki:
http://clashofclans.wikia.com/wiki/Experience
http://clashofclans.wikia.com/wiki/Decorations

Answer (score 4):

> **In Clash of Clans what does XP do when donating troops to clan?**

XP really does nothing. You just receive XP for donating troops. Like the other answers mentioned, XP is a rough indication of how much investment a player has made in their account. Some clans will accept players with a certain minimum level, but the level doesn't necessarily indicate the strength of the player.

> **In Clash of Clans when requesting troops from clan, can one do it to often?**

When you request troops, you have a 20 minutes countdown before being able to request again. This is what limits how often you can request troops.

UPDATE: Due to an update, that countdown now depends on the level of the clan. The countdown changes to 15 minutes at lv 2 and 10 minutes at lv 7.

> **I notice when you donate you get XP. Is there some way to see another players XP**

You cannot see another player's XP, but you can see their current level.

> **and then if it's negative or something no one would donate troops to you?**

No, how people decide to donate or not is up to them. Some people always donate troops, some people never donate troops... everyone has their own way. I personally donate troops only:

- if a new member has at least a few donations
- if an older member has at most 3 times the number of received troops than donated troops (i.e. if someone has 200 donated and received troops, I would give them, if they have 1000 received troops and 10 donated troops, I won't)

> **So what I'm really wondering is how do I know if I'm requesting too many troops compared to how many troops I donate**

It all depends on the players you are playing with. If you're in a clan where almost nobody donates troops but only requests, well, you are bound to be donating more than they do and you get nothing (beneficial to your account besides some exp) in return. In an ideal clan, you will have a lot of donated and received troops for all members.

One rule of thumb I have been seeing in many clans is the 1:3 ratio of donated against received troops, which means that as long as you have less than 3 times received troops than donated troops, you are doing good. Exceed that ratio for received troops and you will be considered to be requesting too much, for such a particular clan.

> **but from the answers it sounds like there's no connection?**

Right, there's no connection and it's really up to players and how they believe the system to be. You are free to decide how you want it to work, but don't remember to be fair to your fellow clan mates.

I wouldn't want to be in a clan where no one donates troops. Castle troops are useful to defend your base and save your resources, and they can be what turns a defeat into a victory in an attack.

I hope I have addressed all your points :)

Answer (score 3):

You can only gain XP, you cannot lose XP. Gain enough XP and you level up, and you can see your level and progress at the top-left corner of the screen.

When you view someone's profile, you can see their current level as well.

Levels don't mean anything. They don't contribute to anything except your [E.P.E.E.N](http://www.wowwiki.com/Equipment_Potency_EquivalencE_Number).

Donating troops is simple: Anytime someone requests troops, you can donate up to 5 troops to that person. There is no other limitation.

Comment: So there's no point in donating troops?

Comment: You gain levels =D

Comment: The point for donating troops is to help out your other clan mates who, in turn, help you out. By donating troops to them, you're giving them additional troops that they couldn't build themselves (don't have access to that troop, don't have access to that level of troops, don't have space to build more of those troops, etc). While experience doesn't have any gameplay benefits, troop donation is still hugely important.

Comment: There is also an achievment for donating, which has a quite large gems reward comparing to the other achievments.